# Why connectivity plugin network handler not working when navigation happens

Tags: c#, xamarin, windows-phone-8, uwp, xamarin.uwp

In case the network connectivity isn’t on to check if it is off, so, that I’m using to connectivity plug in.

I'm calling this code in ***ViewModelLocator*** class

```
Private static async void NetworkConnectivityChanged(object sender,Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e){}
CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged = NetworkConnectivityChanged;
```

In my windows app after navigating if network connectivity status changed … Here this event is not fire but if not using navigation, we change the network status and it happens it's working.

Answer (score 4):

The workaround is to implement the ***native network change handler*** on Winphone or UWP side and stop handling of network change on PCL side for just Winphone and UWP. You can do this by checking the platform before handling.

Create a new Network.cs class with the following code(This detects if there is any change in network connection)

```
 public class InternetConnectionChangedEventArgs : EventArgs

{

    public InternetConnectionChangedEventArgs(bool isConnected)

    {

        this.isConnected = isConnected;

    }



    public bool IsConnected

    {

        get { return this.isConnected; }

    }



    private bool isConnected;

}



public static class Network

{

    public static event EventHandler<InternetConnectionChangedEventArgs>

        InternetConnectionChanged;



    static Network()

    {

        NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += (s) =>

        {

            if (InternetConnectionChanged != null)

            {

                var arg = new InternetConnectionChangedEventArgs(IsConnected);

                InternetConnectionChanged(null, arg);

            }

        };

    }



    public static bool IsConnected

    {

        get

        {

            var profile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

            var isConnected = (profile != null

                && profile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() ==

                NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess);

            return isConnected;

        }

    }

}
```

Then in the app.xaml.cs in UWP or WinPhone register the network change handler in ***OnLaunched*** event like below

```
Network.InternetConnectionChanged += this.Network_InternetConnectionChanged;
```

and here is the event handler

```
 private void Network_InternetConnectionChanged(object sender,InternetConnectionChangedEventArgs e)

    {
      if(e.IsConnected){
         ///code to handle when the internet connectivity is there
      }
      else{
        //code to handle when the internet connectivity is lost
      }

    }
```